How to format text in Drupal - Account Settings?
I'm working on the activation email that gets sent out when you approve an account in Drupal, does anyone know how to format text in it? Specifically, I'd like to make some font bold.
I've tried  and , as well as **. Strangely enough both  and  showed up as single asterisk (*) in the email that was sent out.
Here's the back-end:

And here's what gets sent out:

I thought there might be a setting that needs to be changed in Config - Content Authoring - CKEditor or Text formats, but couldn't find anything that jumped out at me, besides unchecking "Limit allowed HTML tags" in Filtered HTML.

These emails have always been plain text. You'll need to install a module if you want them to be html. See e.g. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/270894/how-to-send-the-emails-related-to-the-user-account-in-html

Thank you, great to know!
